# Como poner imagenes y videos en un "textarea"

Tags: php, imagen, textarea

Quiero hacer que en un textarea puedan adjuntar una imagen, es un sitio en php, donde pueden publicar comentarios rapido y sin registrarse.

Este es mi código para crear un nuevo tema:

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_GET["respuestas"]))
  $respuestas = $_GET['respuestas'];
 else
  $respuestas = 0;
 if(isset($_GET["identificador"]))
  $identificador = $_GET['identificador'];
 else
  $identificador = 0;
?>
<table>
<form name="form" action="agregar.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="identificador" value="<?php echo $identificador;?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="respuestas" value="<?php echo $respuestas;?>">
    <tr>
  <td>Autor </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="autor"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mensaje</td>
      <td><textarea name="mensaje" cols="50" rows="5" required="required"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar Mensaje"></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: lo que deseas es algo similar a area de respuestas-preguntas de esta pagina? o cual es exactamente tu duda?

Comment: Hola, no se si se responde aquí, no lo entiendo mucho todavía, no, lo que quiero hacer es que ademas de escribir en ese textarea puedan adjuntar una imagen o gif, no se si se entiende, algo como facebook, que en la publicación puedes agregar imagenes y arriba está el texto, algo así busco.

Comment: Hola @MatiPHP, creo que lo que tú buscas es un editor WYSIWYG, una búsqueda en google y encontrarás varias opciones 

Comment: Tienes algun tutorial de como incluirlo en php en español?

Comment: No @MatiPHP :( te lo debo

Comment: Probé con el editor WYSIWYG, pero no me deja publicar el comentario, hay que ejecutar alguna consulta en mysql o algo?